# Class.getMethod when parameter is varargs

Tags: java, reflection, variadic-functions

I need to call [Class.getMethod(java.lang.String, java.lang.Class...)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29) to get a method where one of the varargs parameters is a varargs.

Currently I'm trying:

```
// to get jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(RowMapper, Object...)
jdbcTemplate.getClass().getMethod("queryForObject", RowMapper.class, Object.class);
```

Which results, not surprisingly in

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(java.lang.String,     org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper, java.lang.Object)
at java.lang.Class.throwNoSuchMethodException(Class.java:283)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:825)
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You need to provide an array type instead:

```
getMethod("queryForObject", RowMapper.class, Object[].class);
```

Basically a varargs parameter *is* an array, just with an extra bit of metadata telling the compiler to allow that array to be specified as a sequence of elements instead of a single expression.

Comment: Thanks. I knew they were arrays, just didn't remember that Type[].class was valid syntax. Scala has been spoiling me. Will click accepted when SO lets me ... in about 5 mins.